# can i force redirect part of my website to https using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

can i force redirect part of my website to https using .htaccess ?

in my website i want to redirect http://domainname.com to https://domainname.com
and in admin part i don't want to use https
like http://domainname.com/admin/ will remain http://domainname.com/admin/ i don't want https in admin folder

how can i do it using .htaccess?

Thanks

Comment: This certainly is possible from a technical point of view - but the idea is surprising. Most likely you require some form of authorization to enter that admin area? If so, using a non encrypted connection for that area will expose your credentials and everything else. Is that really a wise choice? Why? If you already have a SSL certificate installed, why not use it in a consequent manner as it is standard these days?

Comment: Another details you need to consider: using different protocol schemes for a single domain will break links between those two sections. None of todays browsers will grant you to refer from `https://example.com/something` to `http://example.com/admin/`. You might not use or need such links, but you should keep that in mind.

Comment: The third aspect that weights in against such attempt: most of todays browsers will first try to use the https protocol whenever possible. Since your http server does listen to such requests you often won't be able to use the http protocol, except for links / bookmarks using hard coded absolute URLs. Because you definitely can _not_ redirect from https to http for that "admin" area.

Comment: i get your point. but all of my form in admin section submit into http. it create issue in form submit. that is why i need to disable https in admin area.

Comment: Then change the form methods. Or even better: use a single base URL which can easily be changed for portability and use relative links from there. You certainly should _not_ enhance the problem of insecure data handling by _adding_ to it.

Comment: website is in opencart 2.2.0 in default opencart don't use https in all page. i need to user https in all page except admin area. when i do it with .htaccess it use https in all page. but all form in admin area submit to http. that is why i need only http in admin area.

Comment: You just repeat what you already wrote. But that does not somehow change the issue you face.

Comment: i am also told you what i need and what i can do and what i can't. anyway i solved it.

Comment: @noobcoder Please add your solution as an answer (and accept it), to help other readers and remove the question from the unanswered question queue. Thanks, much appreciated :)